# Confused about evaluation of lazy sequences

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, lazy-evaluation

I am experimenting with clojure's lazy sequences. In order to see when the evaluation of an item would occur, I created a function called square that prints the result before returning it. I then apply this function to a vector using map.

```
(defn square [x]
  (let [result (*  x x)]
  (println "printing " result)
  result))

(def s (map square [1 2 3 4 5])) ; outputs nothing
```

Here in my declaration of s, the REPL does not output anything. This signals that the computation has not started yet. This appears to be correct. I then do:

```
(first s)
```

The function "first" takes only the first item. So I expect that only 1 will be evaluated. My expectation is the REPL will output the following:

```
printing 1
1
```

However, the REPL outputted the following instead.

```
printing 1
printing 4
printing 9
printing 16
printing 25
1
```

So rather than evaluating only the first item, it seems it evaluates all items, even though I am accessing just the first item.

If the state of a lazy sequence can only be either all values computed and no values computed, then how can it gain the advantages of lazy evaluation? I came from a scheme background and I was expecting more like the behavior of streams. Looks like I am mistaken. Can anyone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Laziness isn't all-or-nothing, but some implementations of seq operate on 'chunks' of the input sequence (see [here](https://blog.fogus.me/2010/01/22/de-chunkifying-sequences-in-clojure/) for an explanation). This is the case for vector which you can test for with `chunked-seq?`:

```
(chunked-seq? (seq [1 2 3 4 5]))
```

When given a collection `map` [checks to see](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/b8132f92f3c3862aa6cdd8a72e4e74802a63f673/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2752) if the underlying sequence is chunked, and if so evaluates the result on a per-chunk basis instead of an element at a time.

The chunk size is usually 32 so you can see this behaviour by comparing the result of

```
(first (map square (vec (range 35))))
```

This should only display a message for the first 32 items and not the entire sequence.

Comment: Is performance the only reason for this deviation from the just-evaluate-enough principle of lazy eval?

Comment: @Lee I wonder why the sseq1 function in the blog you linked is still not yet in the official library. It would have been nice to control the chunk size of a sequence (E.G. if each call makes an http request, it would be nice to make it execute 1 at a time, 32 at a time will consume a lot of resources).